# Redirect code not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the ff.code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Videos</title>
<link href="normal.css" rel="stylesheet" /><script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.videos').click(function(){
        //window.demo.logSectionVisit( "Visited Videos Section" );
        $(location).attr('href',"google.com");
        //alert(0);
        //window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="buttons">
<div id="buttonsleft">
<a href="reset.html" class="reset"><div class="buttonlabel">New Session</div></a>
</div>
<div id="buttonsright">
<a href="" class="videos"><div class="buttonlabel">Videos</div></a>
<a href="" class="slideshows"><div class="buttonlabel">Slide Shows</div></a>
<a href="" class="forms"><div class="buttonlabel">Forms</div></a>
<a href="" class="surveys"><div class="buttonlabel">Surveys</div></a>
<a href="" class="websites"><div class="buttonlabel">Websites</div></a>
<a href="" class="interactive"><div class="buttonlabel">Interactive</div></a>
<a href="" class="admin"><div class="buttonlabel">Admin</div></a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="mainbody">

<div id="links2">

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I wonder why when I click the videos button, it isn't redirecting. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to what Andrew suggests, if you need to have the anchor tag, either remove the href attribute from the anchor or add a `preventDefault()` to the click handler as:

```
$('.videos').click(function(e){
    // note that if you redirect to google.com only, it a relative redirect...
    // so to go to the actual www.google.com site, use the full url
    $(location).attr('href',"http://www.google.com");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: here's the full working sample: http://jsbin.com/ikayu3/edit in any case Andrerws is the better solution/answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to uncomment the line:

//window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";

and comment the line:

$(location).attr('href',"google.com");

Comment: After that I suggest you should to substitute window.location.href with window.location.replace, as it keeps parent page out of browser history, avoiding never-ending back loops.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<a href="" class="videos"><div class="buttonlabel">Videos</div></a>
```

try

```
<div class="buttonlabel videos">Videos</div>
```

Comment: This is close, thanks a lot, i never knew its possible to have two classes in one div! :)